# validation using script of single web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hi everybody i want to validate a single web form using this script

but its not in correct way

```
 fields.each(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   if (field_values[$(this).attr('id')] = null) {
     $(this).addClass('error');
     $(this).effect("shake", {
       times: 3
     }, 50);

     error++;
     alert(1);
   } else {
     $(this).addClass('valid');
     alert(2);
     $('#progress_text').html('33% Complete');
     $('#progress').css('width', '113px');

     //slide steps
     $('#first_step').slideUp();
     $('#second_step').slideDown();
   }
 });
```

how to form the if condition in this script can anyone tell me thanks in advance

Comment: What is field_values? What is the error or the unexpected behavour that you are having ? BTW, instead of `$(this).attr('id')`, you should use `this.id`.

Comment: What do you mean by `how to form the if condition in this script` ?

Comment: IM ASKING  how we will check the availability of textbox and dropdown in that if

Comment: "var value =.." is not used and you haven't told us what "field_values" is. Also it is unclear what you mean by the "check the availability of textbox and dropdown". Do you mean the available values or the actual HTML controls? How are these controls added to the page?

Comment: @Chris yes the available values of textboxs and dropdown

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of this. If you are interested in the fields having a value then should your if statement be like this: **if(value==''){..throw your error}else{..all good}** ? I don't understand why you are checking the element id.